# Database Driven Dependant Dynamic DropDownList on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down list as follows in my AddProduct.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>    
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubBrand" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

At the Code Behind File I have used these codes to get my Brand Drop down List to be database driven

```
ddlBrand.DataSource = brandManager.getAllBrand();
            ddlBrand.DataTextField = "BrandName";
            ddlBrand.DataValueField = "BrandId";
            ddlBrand.DataBind();
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Value = "0";
            item.Text = "--Select Brand--";
            ddlBrand.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

Im trying to get my SubBrand Drop Down List to be dynamic and change according to what was selected in the Brand drop down list. Both drop down lists are next to each other and so I'm not sure how to get the value of the selected brand as soon as it is selected. I'm planning parse in the selected value into the data base using this statement in my class that retrieves values from the database.

```
   "SELECT SubBrandId,SubBrandName " +
   " DateOfBirth FROM SubBrand WHERE " +
   " BrandId = @inBrandId"
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a Brand gets selected you probably want a post back of the selected item:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BrandSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In code-behind you will have to add the method:

```
protected void BrandSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    int id;
    if (int.TryParse(ddlBrand.SelectedValue, out id)) {
        //Do your thing here with the id of the brand, e.g. bind sub brands.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll get back to you on this when I'm home. Seems like it will work. Thanks a lot :)